# HTML (using CSS) Code for sending an email to given email-id

Tags: html, email

How can i code a HTML (using CSS) file to send an email to me(i.e. to given email-id) by the visitor of that website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using a server-side language, the best you can really do is a `mailto` link. That will open the user's default email editor with the "To" field populated with the value of your `mailto` link. You can create one of those like so:

`<a href="mailto:you@somewhere.com">Email Me!</a>`

It is possible to provide extra information in a `mailto` link, to populate more fields. For example, if you want to provide a subject:

`<a href="mailto:you@somewhere.com?subject=Subject">Email Me!</a>`

You can also provide a value for the `body`, `cc` and `bcc` but I have no idea how well those default values are supported by various email clients.

Also note that this has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with CSS, which is used for styling documents. I've therefore removed the CSS tag from your question.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. You can use a tag:

```
<a href="mailto:youremailaddress">Email Me</a>
```

And this will open a mail client in the **client side**. The client must have it configured for being able to send a email.

If you want to create a form that, when the user presses a button "send" sends you a message, you must use a dynamic language such as PHP.